# solution to cs50 credit problem set in python

Tags: python, cs50

on testing my `credit.py` with Number: `378282246310005`, it gives me invalid

```py
from cs50 import get_int

def main():
    while True:
        h = int(input("Enter credit number: "))
        if h >0:
            break

    odd_sum_digit=0
    even_sum_digit=0

    while (h > 0):
        last_digit= h % 10
        odd_sum_digit += last_digit
        even_digit= int((h / 10) % 10)

        if (2 * even_digit) > 9:
              even_digit = (2 * even_digit)-9
        else:
            even_digit = 2 * even_digit

        even_sum_digit += even_digit

        h=h//100

    sum= odd_sum_digit + even_sum_digit
    print(f"{sum}")  #Test that checksum works.


   if (sum % 10 == 0):

        if ((h >= 4000000000000 and h < 5000000000000) or (h >= 4000000000000000 and h < 5000000000000000)):
            print("VISA")

        elif ((h >= 340000000000000 and h < 350000000000000) or (h >= 370000000000000 and h < 380000000000000)):
            print("AMEX")

        elif (h >= 5100000000000000 and h < 5600000000000000):
            print("MASTERCARD")

        else:
            print("INVALID")
  else:
        print("INVALID")


if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check how large an integer is allowed to be, you will find that your number is out of range. 
Consider using string instead